# How to pass an array of Uri between Activity using Bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to pass an array of Uri to another activity,
to pass an array of String I use simply

```
String[] images=getImagesPathString();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("images", images);
```

But using an array of Uri

```
 Uri[] imagesUri=getImagesUri();
```

this doesn't works because there isn't a method "putUri(Uri x)" in Bundle

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into the Parcelable interface to see how to pass things on an intent

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Maybe you can implement a ParcelableUri class that implements that interface.

Like this (not tested!!):

```
public class ParcelableUri implements Parcelable {

private Uri[] uris;

public ParcelableUri(Parcel in) {
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();

    int lenght = in.readInt();
    for(int i=0; i<=lenght; i++){           
        uris[i]= builder.path(in.readString()).build();
    }
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(uris.length);
    for(int i=0; i<=uris.length; i++){
        dest.writeString(uris[i].toString());
    }
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableUri> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableUri>() {

    public ParcelableUri createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ParcelableUri(in);
    }

    public ParcelableUri[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ParcelableUri[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: Google "implementing parcelable android". Gotta try for yourself first, and come back if you can't get it.

Comment: The array of Uri is nested in another object. I don't know how exactly could do this.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some code. Hope it helps giving you an idea.

Comment: I'm following the sample but in the  private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {...} now I'm arrived at images=in.readArrayList(Class loader) and I have no idea of what I should pass. For the primitives is simply in.readString() etc.

Comment: in.readArray(ArrayList.class.getClassLoader()), i imagine you are using an ArrayList instead of an array in the class of ParcelableUri like @marcin_j propose...

Answer (score 7):

From what I know plain arrays cannot be put into Bundles. But you can put Uri-s into ArrayList and then call Bundle.putParcelableArrayList().

example:

```
 ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
 // fill uris
 bundle.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_URIS, uris);
```

later on:

```
    ArrayList<Parcelable> uris =
            bundle.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_URIS);
    for (Parcelable p : uris) {
        Uri uri = (Uri) p;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where should I put the second code block that you have posted?

Comment: this second block is for reading from bundle, so it should be ie. in your second activity onCreate()

Comment: Great help thank you although I used: ArrayList<Parcelable> uris = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("uriArray"); my code is identical other than that.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the Uri parcelable? You can try to create an array of parcelable elements (Uri) and put it in the Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONObject to wrap any object and stringify it quickle. Going back from string to JSON is really trivial

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
private Uri[] getUris(int requestCode, Intent data) {

        Uri[] uris;

    ClipData clipData = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        clipData = data.getClipData();
    }
    if(clipData != null) {
        uris = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
        for(int i=0;i<clipData.getItemCount();i++) {
            ClipData.Item videoItem = clipData.getItemAt(i);
            Uri videoURI = videoItem.getUri();
            uris[i] = videoURI;
        }
    }
    else {
        uris = new Uri[0];
        Uri videoURI = data.getData();
        uris[0] = videoURI;
    }

    return uris;
    }
```